# Python Class variable changes back to default value when called

Tags: python

I have a python code with a Summary class that i use to log all the work done during execution.
The class looks like :

```
#Summary.py 
class summary : 
   def __init__(self): 
      self.file = None 

   def late_init(self, file_name):
      self.file = open(file_name, "w") 
      self.create_file() 

   def create_file(self):
      self.file.write("bla bla title") 

   def write_info(self, info):
      self.file.write(date() + info)

   def finish(self):
      self.file.close()
```

mySummary is declared in config.py as follows, so i can call it from everywhere

```
#config.py
global mySummary 
mySummary = summary()
```

later down, my main looks like

```
def create_working_directory(): 
   os.mkdir("Output_file") 
   mySummary.late_init("Output_file") #This works and creates the file with the general info in it 

#main.py 
create_working_directory() 
work1() 
mySummary.write_info("Work1 done")
```

This last line outputs `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'`  and printing the type shows that mySummary.file goes from `<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>` to `<class 'NoneType'>` when i call mySummary.write_info.

Why would that change and how can i fix this?

Comment: btw, in `config.py` the line `global mySummary` does nothing. You can delete it.

Comment: Your `write_info` looks like it should give a `NameError`, because it uses an undefined `self`. (Several of your methods are missing the `self` parameter.)

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant `import` statements for each file.

Comment: All my class functions have the self parameter, forgot to add it, will edit in a sec

Comment: `os.mkdir("Output_file")` makes a **directory**, but then `mySummary.late_init("Output_file")` tries to open it as a **file**. That's likely going to cause problems.

Comment: (I assume you also meant to write: `def write_info(self, info):`). Another option is that somewhere you create another instance of `Summary()`. This would leave the `file` attribute as `None`.

Comment: `f = open(file, "w")` creates the file if it doesn't exist already. As i've said the file is created and gets the information from `create_file()` without problems.

Comment: @quamrana as it's showed, the statements follow each other in the `main()` of the code so i really don't see where i could create a second instance of it

Comment: There's no way for us to solve this problem without seeing the full code.  Don't give us bits and pieces.

Comment: How does the `mySummary` in main.py relate to the `mySummary` in config.py?

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, it's a 5k line program so i'm trying to show the important bits

Comment: @slothrop and quamrana were right, the problem came from bad imports. Changing my imports from `from Summary import summary` to `from .Summary import summary` fixed it. I guess it's because of the installation changing the location of the files

Comment: `from Summary import summary` I don't understand that import.  The class name is `Summary`, and the variable itself is named `mySummary`.  So what is `summary`?

Comment: The file is called `Summary.py` and i named the class `summary` with no capital to avoid confusion when calling the imports (and misstyped when i copied it...)